# Overriding HTML img with CSS

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

My jpeg is a pixelated obese shell of its former self... Is it possible to actually override html img height/width code with a css stylesheet instead of just streching an already adjusted image? The reason I ask is that a client has me working with godaddy's quick shopping cart (evil). The code it generates changes the size of the image in the html. Godaddy only allows css alterations, which is how I've managed to at least stretch the image back to original size. Unfortunately, it seems the html is applied to the image first despite the img css I've written, and then the css expands the image to nasty pixels. It's possible that, in addition to the height and width specifications in the html, godaddy has actually already converted the image to the smaller size on their server, though their techs deny this and the code would then be redundant. The CSS I'm using is pasted below, as is the unchangeable code that GoDaddy generates.

```
//FROM CSS

td.imageRow {
  padding: 10px 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:192px;
  height:250px;
}

.productTable img {
  border: 0 none;
  width:192px;
  height:250px;
}

.productTable a {
  width:192px;
  height:250px;
}


//FROM HTML
<tbody>
<tr><td class="imageRow"><a href="/Logo.htm">
    <img width="122" height="160" alt="Logo" src="/images/13129490572471789450105.jpeg">
    </a></td><td class="noBorder"></td><td class="noBorder"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="titleRow"><a href="/Logo.htm">Logo</a></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="priceRow"></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="spacer">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

Comment: If you view the image by itself in a new tab/window. What dimension does the image turn out to be?

Comment: It's the resized, smaller version, but the html has no height width definitions in the img tag--which leads me to believe godaddy is doing it on the server. That might be it then, jquery or not. But why would they have redundant code on the regular site? @Webars I'm going to try loading that jquery code anyway. Might catch it before it's converted.

Comment: it's generally a good idea to add the width and height to img tags in html and this makes the place the image appears on the screen already have the correct layout, then if, for some reason, the image doesn't appear, the layout of page won't be messed up... So what I am saying, is that whether you are using the attr to resize the image or not, it's generally a good idea to have those tags in there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the !important override:

```
.productTable img {
  border: 0 none;
  width:192px !important;
  height:250px!important;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/GDVXw/ for an example.

Just to illustrate, I've stretched the image a bunch here so you can see more clearly that the overrides works: http://jsfiddle.net/GDVXw/1/.

Comment: Yea, I just learned about jsfiddle, so something awesome came out of this. Unfortunately, the image that you stretched I downloaded and noticed was originally smaller, so it's pixelated when enlarged. Same issue on the godaddy site--they're resizing it to a smaller size after I upload it, and then when it's called in the code and run through my css, it enlarges, but it's pixelated. I'm pretty sure that's what's happening.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. They're probably using a server-side technology to size the images. Not much you can do in that case. You might want to check out the shopping cart plugins in WordPress if this is a dealbreaker, or another CMS you like and are comfortable with :).

Comment: It's very interesting, your example works even without !important. But as far as I know, this code must not work at all, because inline styles always override external and internal css styles. Did you test your code directly in a browser?

Comment: I haven't tested it outside jsfiddle yet. !important will override inline styles, but now that I think about it, I guess I should know that CSS width will override image width set in the HTML attribute. I think that was a gap in my own knowledge!

Comment: Ha, I'm glad we're learning from this one. I had hope that we could catch it before it was converted server-side, because the way the images are used throughout the site in different places and in different sizes, it's as if they're converted on the fly or something. No dice. @Lee thank you too for explaining why even after server-side conversion they'd add the html sizing too. I truly appreciate all the help.

Comment: They likely are converted on the fly, using an image-manipulation library like ImageMagick or GD2. Those are software packages that crop/resize etc images. The conversion is done before any of your client side changes (JS or CSS) are loaded.